# Pandas to reversible string?

Tags: python, pandas

I run into this situation all the time, where in production or development I'm messing with a dataframe, fix something, then have to write a unittest for it.  Many times it sucks to try and develop some relevant test data and it would be much faster to have the production data dump some lines to a string that I can "ctrl-c", paste into my test and load into a df there. Is there a way to do this?

The problem with `pd.to_string` is that object information is lost, there's no easy way to deserialize the data, and even if there was, it would got through type inference which breaks data consistency in pandas all the time.

If we could screen print a pickle using something like `pd.to_pickle` that would be ideal I think.  Any one out there have a more efficient solution to this?

example would be like:

```
s_1 = pd.to_pickle()
print(s_1)

#copy and paste the out put into s_2

s_2 = 'paste printed binary output of s_1 in here.'
df = pd.read_picke(s_2)
```

Comment: @DaniMesejo - type inference.  Also the need for an intermediary file.  I'm trying to eliminate steps in my testing as much as possible.

Comment: BTW, you don't need an intermediary file with csv, s_2 can be a csv representation and use stringio, as for the types you can also save that info also and pass it to read_csv

Comment: @DaniMesejo- maybe I can do the same thing with the pickle output?  I'm giving that shot right now.

Comment: @DaniMesejo I was about to write the same, except that you would need `BytesIO`, not `StringIO`.

Comment: But why pickle, if you are creating unit test, is not better if i'm reading the test and see what the the data looks like instead of looking at some binary string?

Comment: You can use `pickle.dumps(df)` to get a bytestring of the pickle representation. `pickle.loads(...)` would get you a perfect copy of the dataframe (`df.to_pickle` and `pd.read_pickle` do the same, just with files instead of bytestrings). What you do with that bytestring (to clipboard, print, ...) is up to you. But as @DaniMesejo pointed out, having binary data in unit tests might not be what you are looking for. If type inference is all that worries you, you could store the data and column dtypes in a human-readable format like csv.

Comment: @DaniMesejo - yes and no.  The reality is when developing we often need to split the difference between readability and time spent.  Academically, I would agree with you, and urge people not to abuse this.  In "reality" though, I spend way to much time setting up mocks and would like to cut down that time where appropriate.

Comment: @NiklasMertsch - pickle.dumps works.  Would you mind posting your solution as answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pickle` to store the dataframe to a bytestring with `df_bytes = pickle.dumps(df)`. You can then copy/paste/print/save/whatever that bytestring and restore the dataframe later by using `df2 = pickle.loads(df_bytes)`.